# How to access DisposableList in C# coding for Microsoft.ML.onnxruntime?

Tags: c#, .net, onnx, onnxruntime

May i know how to display the values circled in yellow in the console.
i tried

```
using (var results = Session.Run(outputs))
            {
                var highestIndex = results.First().AsTensor<long>().First();
                Console.WriteLine(highestIndex);

                var values = results.Last().Value;
                Console.WriteLine(values);
            }
```

The [0] value of the results i extract in highestIndex,
I need to extract the [1.] values of the values, inside it is in First(), again in First() and Last() values circled in yellow.
I just want to display in console like

```
1
1.7285347E-05
0.9999827
```

[image]

Tried in stack overflow, no one could help.
I am python dev, so no sure of c# coding.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I found the way

```
            using (var results = Session.Run(outputs))
            {
                var highestIndex = results.First().AsTensor<long>().First();
                Console.WriteLine(highestIndex);
                var seq = results.Last().AsEnumerable<NamedOnnxValue>();
                var map = seq.First().AsDictionary<Int64, float>();
                var values = map.First().Value;
                Console.WriteLine("Index {0} with Probability {1}", map.First().Key, map.First().Value);
                Console.WriteLine("Index {0} with Probability {1}", map.Last().Key, map.Last().Value);
            }
```